# Python - Decode text read from input file

Tags: python, decode, codec, normalize

Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere but I couldn't find a solution to my issue.

I am reading in a file with service references & names from a satellite receiver. I am trying to normalize the service names but the issue is that the file can contain data from many different satellites and also many different languages.

I had this code that handled a good few of the Irish names, changing RTÉ One to RTE One etc.

```
name = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicode(name, 'utf_8')).encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
```

name is read from the input file and it is like this:

```
RTÃ‰ One
```

That all works fine but then I come across a service name like this:

```
Î‰Ï€ÎµÎ¹ÏÎ¿Ï‚ TV1
```

It can't handle the above codec, it's obviously not utf_8?

I tried to change the above code to this:

```
name = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', force_decode(name)).encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
```

And where force_decode was a function as follows:

```
def force_decode(string, codecs=['latin_1', 'cp857', 'cp866', 'cp1252', 'cp855', 'iso8859_5', 'iso8859_9', 'utf_8']):
for i in codecs:
    try:
        return string.decode(i)
    except (Exception) as exception:
        print "Error decoding name!! ", exception
        pass

print "cannot decode url %s" % ([string])
```

What happens now is that the above comes out as simply TV1. I'd like if I was able to decode whatever Î‰Ï€ÎµÎ¹ÏÎ¿Ï‚ was also.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a nightmare problem. If you really don't have any way to know the encoding, and the encoding will be arbitrary and changing, you're going to get errors when you guess wrong. No way around it.

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the answer lol.. Thanks for the reply, I will need to think of a different approach perhaps!